# ASP.net dropdown values, do I need to check if they are numbers?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm not sure about this.

I have a dropdownlist that is filled with a collection in code behind. The values are numbers.

When I postback, do I need to check if those values are still numbers and they were not changed?

Or this is done automatically by the ASP.net runtime?

I'm trying to avoid any change by a malicious user.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EnableEventValidation should take care of this for you.  Here is the MSDN documentation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx.

As StriplingWarrior mentioned, the viewstate could be tampered with which would, I believe, hinder the ability for the event validation feature to work.  I would still check the the input yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should check both that it's still a number and that it's within the expected range of values.

Answer (score 0):

They are actually strings that hopefully contain only digits in your case.

Since you will probably have to convert the string to an int when an item is selected, you can check at the point of conversion.

Comment: Thank you, I do check them, but seeing my code I wondered if this was needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concern about security then it will be better to check if its number or not. 
Also you can associate Custom Server side Validation to check type & range